# How to access and afterwards change a variable outside of a loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am working on an encounter system for a game I am currently developing for fun. The stats and medkits are just placeholders for the sake of building the system before finishing the game, which functions fine other than this issue. I want the medkits variable to be accessed inside the loop and afterward, say if there were a second encounter, for that variable to be changed to the proper number. For example, if I use a medkit in the first encounter, I should have one less in the next. no idea how to do this as this is my first real try at making a legitimate game. Any functional solution would be great!

I'd also like to add that I know that the 3rd option doesn't work and the enemy doesn't fight back yet, but that will be no problem for me. I only want answers for this particular issue.

```
charisma = int(60)
strength = int(25)
endurance = int(40)
intelligence = int(70)
capacity = int(50)
from random import randint
medkits = 2

def encounter(enemy):
  print("Engaging "+enemy+"!")
  print()
  y = 10 + (strength*.10)
  enhealth = int(100)
  enhealth = int(enhealth-y)
  health = int(100)
  med = int(medkits)
  while True:
    print("Pick your move!")
    print("1. Smack with shovel")
    print("2. Use a medkit (you have "+str(med)+" medkits)")
    print("3. Attempt escape")
    enc = input("I will try to (put a #): ")
    if "1" in enc:
      x = randint(0, 100)
      if x < 80:
        enhealth = int(enhealth-y)
        print()
        print("You hit "+enemy+" for "+str(y)+" damage!")
        print()
      else:
        print()
        print("Miss!")
        print()
    elif "2" in enc:
      if med > 0:
        print()
        print("You used a medkit!")
        print()
        health = health+30
        med = med-1
        print("Health is at "+str(health))
        print()
      else:
        print("You're out of medkits!")
    if enhealth <= int(0):
      print(enemy+" has been defeated! Well done!")
      break

encounter("Cornelius")
```

Comment: You typically write "charisma = int(60)" as: charisma = 60

Comment: Your posted code contains a lot of overhead.  It requires user input -- you should hard-code the case you want us to work on.  You haven't shown the current output (although you did describe how the program *should* work).

Comment: Do you know the python keyword `global`.  Currently you have 2 instances of `medkit` one in the function encounter and the other at file level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around this is to define all of your initial values outside of the function (which you already do), then pass them in as additional variables of the function, and make the function recursive.  Use a `return` statement at the end of each run.  If the enemy is still alive and you want to run the function again, the `return encounter(enemy, y, enhealth, health, med)` command just calls the function again, passing in the values it updated before.  When the enemy is dead, a simple `return` quits the function all together.

```
from random import randint

def encounter(enemy, y, enhealth, health, med):
    print("Engaging "+enemy+"!\n")
    print("Pick your move!")
    print("1. Smack with shovel")
    print("2. Use a medkit (you have "+str(med)+" medkits)")
    print("3. Attempt escape")
    enc = input("I will try to (put a #): ")
    if enc == '1':
        if randint(0,100) < 80:
            enhealth = int(enhealth - y)
            print("\nYou hit "+enemy+" for "+str(y)+" damage!\n")
        else:
            print("\nMiss!\n")
    elif enc == '2':
        if med > 0:
            print("\nYou used a medkit!\n")
            health += 30
            med -= 1
            print("\nHealth is at " + str(health) + "\n")
        else:
            print("\nYou're out of medkits!\n")
    if enhealth <= 0:
        print(enemy + " has been defeated! Well done!")
        return
    return encounter(enemy, y, enhealth, health, med)


strength = int(25)
y = 10 + (strength*.10)
enhealth = int(100 - y)
health = int(100)
med = 2
enemy = "Cornelius"
encounter(enemy, y, enhealth, health, med)
```

Instead of trying to keep track of all those variables though, you may want to consider storing all of the stats inside a Python dictionary to pass in and out of functions.  That way you could also `return` the dictionary if you're finished with `encounter()` but wanted to keep the same resulting stats to pass into a new function.

Comment: The global function served better for my intentions, but thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome.  You could always apply the same concept by having `encounter()` call other functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable med is set to medkits each time you call your encounter function.
For example, if you call encounter("Cornelius") and use 1 medkit, and then call encounter("Cornelius"), med is set to int(medkits) again. Currently, med is set to 2 each function call. I fixed your code so it now achieves your intended functionality. Cool game and keep coding!

```
charisma = int(60)
strength = int(25)
endurance = int(40)
intelligence = int(70)
capacity = int(50)
from random import randint
med = 2

def encounter(enemy):
  print("Engaging "+enemy+"!")
  print()
  y = 10 + (strength*.10)
  enhealth = int(100)
  enhealth = int(enhealth-y)
  health = int(100)
  global med
  while True:
    print("Pick your move!")
    print("1. Smack with shovel")
    print("2. Use a medkit (you have "+str(med)+" medkits)")
    print("3. Attempt escape")
    enc = input("I will try to (put a #): ")
    if "1" in enc:
      x = randint(0, 100)
      if x < 80:
        enhealth = int(enhealth-y)
        print()
        print("You hit "+enemy+" for "+str(y)+" damage!")
        print()
      else:
        print()
        print("Miss!")
        print()
    elif "2" in enc:
      if med > 0:
        print()
        print("You used a medkit!")
        print()
        health = health+30
        med = med-1
        print("Health is at "+str(health))
        print()
      else:
        print("You're out of medkits!")
    if enhealth <= int(0):
      print(enemy+" has been defeated! Well done!")
      break

encounter("Cornelius")
encounter("Cornelius")
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks a lot!